# LINQ query much slower than SQL equivalent

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, query-optimization

I've written a linq query, which when I grab the T-SQL from profiler and check stats, is very bad. The execution plan is also so complicated as to be unreadable. The same query converted to SQL, is orders of magnitude better in terms of reads.

Can anyone make any suggestions how I might improve the performance of the LINQ query, or do I just need to accept it and use a stored procedure?

For reference, there are 235 ids in the input, and the reason the SQL is getting them from a table is it's just easier, but the ids are the same.

Linq:

```
    var itemchangeList = (from itm in db.AS_ITM
                          join rsi in db.AS_ITM_RTL_STR on itm.ID_ITM equals rsi.ID_ITM
                          join sti in db.AS_ITM_STK on itm.ID_ITM equals sti.ID_ITM
                          join pi in db.ID_IDN_PS on itm.ID_ITM equals pi.ID_ITM
                          join ics in db.AS_ITM_CustomFilters on itm.ID_ITM equals ics.ItemId into icsGroup
                          from ics in icsGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()  // Perform left join
                          join cs in db.CustomFilters on ics.CustomFilterId equals cs.CustomFilterId into csGroup
                          from cs in csGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()    // Perform left join
                          where rsi.ID_CPY == WsKey.CompanyID && rsi.ID_STR_RT == WsKey.StoreID && itemIds.Contains(itm.ID_ITM)
                          group new { itm, sti, pi,cs } by itm.ID_ITM into grouped
                          select new Contexts.Items.PendingItemChange
                          {
                              ItemId = grouped.Key,
                              AuthForSale = grouped.FirstOrDefault().itm.FL_AZN_FR_SLS == "1" ? true : false,
                              SaleType = null,
                              StoreManaged = grouped.FirstOrDefault().itm.StoreManaged,
                              ApacsCode = null,
                              ProhibitEmployeeDiscount = grouped.FirstOrDefault().pi.FL_DSC_EM_ALW == "1" ? true : false,
                              ProhibitPriceModification = grouped.FirstOrDefault().itm.FL_ITM_PRC_MOD == "1" ? true : false,
                              RequiredMargin = grouped.FirstOrDefault().sti.Margin,
                              ProductTagsList = grouped.Select(x => x.cs.CustomFilterId.ToString()).Distinct().ToList(),
                              EligibleForOnlineDelivery = grouped.FirstOrDefault().sti.EligibleForOnlineDelivery,
                              DepositItemId = grouped.FirstOrDefault().pi.ID_ITM_DS,
                              Analgesic = grouped.FirstOrDefault().itm.Analgesic == "1" ? true : false,
                              CountryOfOrigin = grouped.FirstOrDefault().sti.CountryOfOrigin,
                              Brand = grouped.FirstOrDefault().sti.Brand,
                              MiscInfo = grouped.FirstOrDefault().sti.MiscText
                          }).ToList();
```

SQL:

```
SELECT
    itm.ID_ITM AS ItemId,
    CASE WHEN MAX(CAST(itm.FL_AZN_FR_SLS AS INT)) = 1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS AuthForSale,
    CASE WHEN MAX(CAST(itm.StoreManaged AS INT)) = 1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS StoreManaged,
    CASE WHEN MAX(CAST(pi.FL_DSC_EM_ALW AS INT)) = 1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS ProhibitEmployeeDiscount,
    CASE WHEN MAX(CAST(itm.FL_ITM_PRC_MOD AS INT)) = 1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS ProhibitPriceModification,
    MAX(sti.Margin) AS RequiredMargin,
    CASE WHEN MAX(CAST(sti.EligibleForOnlineDelivery AS INT)) = 1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS EligibleForOnlineDelivery,
    MAX(pi.ID_ITM_DS) AS DepositItemId,
    CASE WHEN MAX(CAST(itm.Analgesic AS INT)) = 1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS Analgesic,
    MAX(sti.CountryOfOrigin) AS CountryOfOrigin,
    MAX(sti.Brand) AS Brand,
    MAX(sti.MiscText) AS MiscInfo,
    STRING_AGG(cs.CustomFilterId, ',') AS ProductTagsList
FROM AS_ITM itm
JOIN AS_ITM_RTL_STR rsi ON itm.ID_ITM = rsi.ID_ITM
JOIN AS_ITM_STK sti ON itm.ID_ITM = sti.ID_ITM
JOIN ID_IDN_PS pi ON itm.ID_ITM = pi.ID_ITM
LEFT JOIN AS_ITM_CustomFilters ics ON itm.ID_ITM = ics.ItemId
LEFT JOIN CustomFilters cs ON ics.CustomFilterId = cs.CustomFilterId
WHERE itm.ID_ITM IN (SELECT ItemId FROM PendingItemChanges)
GROUP BY itm.ID_ITM;
```

Linq stats:

[image: Linq stats]

SQL stats:

[image: sql stats]

Comment: I do not see any reason why do you use `grouped.FirstOrDefault()` and there is no similar operators in your SQL. So, you have just created bad and ineffective LINQ query.

Comment: I just want the first record of each grouping by id. The SQL part is doing exactly the same thing with grouping by id and the 'max' function on each other record getting the last row. So they are equivalent.

Comment: Use MAX then, EF Core will generate ineffective SQL for `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: And using `join` in LINQ with EF is almost always the wrong approach.  Just use your Navigation Properties.